# Python multiprocessing not executing per item but rather per character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple environments (DEV, INT, PRD). I will like to build each environment asynchronously using python multiprocessing.

In my example below, build_environments is a list as such : ['DEV', 'UAT', 'PRD'].

```
def thread_set(self,environment):
        max_workers = 3
        concurrent = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers)
        with concurrent as ex:
            ex.map(self.build, environment)
        return environment

def multibuild(self):
        build_environments = self.myparser.getEnvironments()     
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
             results = pool.imap(self.thread_set, build_environments)
             pool.close() 
             pool.join()

def build(self,build_environment):
        print(build_environment)
```

When i execute multibuild(), the print statement in build() function is printing and executing in this manner as shown below.

```
U
A
T
D
E
V
P
R
D
```

But I will want the build() print function to be :

```
DEV
UAT
PRD
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Both mapping functions require lists as arguments. The inner one only receives a string and splits it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `print` is not thread-safe. Use logging instead.

```
import logging

# environment is a string which is iterable, only one
# character is getting passed to build
def thread_set(self,environment):
    max_workers = 3
    concurrent = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers)
    with concurrent as ex:
        ex.map(self.build, (environment,)) # place environment in a container, a list should work, too.
    return environment

# replace the print statement with logging

def build(self,build_environment):
    # print(build_environment) (Not thread-safe.)
    logging.info(build_environment)
```

Reference: [An Intro to Threading in Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: thank you but this does not really answer the question. Printing was just an example, but i need to use the environment in that function. However instead of getting an environment, i get a letter.

Comment: I made a change. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: In the future you may run into an issue where you need to pass more than one argument. See this answer that addresses that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981/1913726